why i am getting blank pdf from s3 url? in rails using wicked and carrierwave
This is my code to store the html template as pdf in s3, for 1 template its working fine, but for others two its returting blank pdf, no errors.
I have tried debugging it, but its seem all the steps are correct.
Here is my code:
        pdf_html = ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
          template: 'layouts/test_pdf1',
          layout: false,
          locals: { license: user.parent.license, email: user.parent.email, phone: user.parent.phone_number,
                    name: 'Firm Name', address: 'Address', broker_firm_city: 'City',
                    initials: params[:initials] , local_assigns: params }
        )

          pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_html)

        # Save the generated PDF to an in-memory file
        file = Tempfile.new(["temp_#{user.uid}_#{DateTime.now.to_i}", '.pdf'], encoding: 'ascii-8bit')
        file.write(pdf)
        file.rewind

        # Upload the PDF to S3 using CarrierWave
        uploader = UploadUploader.new
        uploader.store!(file) # Directly uploads to S3

        # Optionally create a document record in the database
        document = ::Document.create!(user_id: user.id, upload: uploader, doc_type: 'Passport', doc_category: 'uploaded', profile_id: Profile.last.id)

        # Clean up the temp file
        file.close
        file.unlink

I have tried debugging it by doing this in rails c step by step, and its working fine, i mean i am not getting any empty file like thing

is the pdf being created correctly? what is the output from uploader.store!(file)?

I saved the pdf in my local, using file open, and its creating blank pdf, white screen, i think its bacause of too much javascript code? not sure, but when i try same with normal html its works fine.

Should mention that in the question. Issue isn't AWS or carrierwave -- just PDF generation.  And yes javascript in the template complicates things.
